# Jquery: How to window.open() with no valid href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have web page on which I display a lot of summary information. I would like to be able to, by clicking a right button or link, to open up a new window and display the underlying data.

For many reasons I cannot request the underlying data again from the server once the summary information page is generated

What I would like to achieve is:

- Embed the underlying data in a hidden
  table in the summary page
- On thesummary page I also provide a 'drill
  down' button
- Open a new window upon a    click of
  this button
- Inject the    content of the hidden
  table into the    new windows.

What I want to learn are:

1. What to pass to the href parameter
   of the window.open(href) function?
   How to get a reference to the new
   window and inject the content?

I am using jquery 1.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `about:blank`.
`open` returns a new `window` object; you can write to its `document`.

However, you should consider using a modal dialog, such as [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using the jQuery UI dialog widget and open a dialog rather than a new window.  It would be dead simple to copy stuff from the DOM into the dialog when it opens.

```
 $('.drilldown-button').click( function() {
       $('<div title="Details"></div>').dialog({
           autoOpen: true,
           modal: false,
           open: function() {
              $('.hidden-details').clone()
                                  .appendTo($(this))
                                  .show();
              // maybe add some handlers, etc. 
           },
           buttons: {
              'Close': function() { $(this).dialog('destroy'); }
              // maybe other buttons for different actions
           }
       });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately due to the volume of the underlying data, a dialog/popup will block the summary page entirely. We would like to be able to view both contents side by side for verification and analysis.